# Can one import statement replace all inner class imports in android?

Tags: java, android, import, hardware

I have this code :

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent ;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener ;
import android.hardware.SensorManager ;
```

Can i replace it with android.hardware.* ; if no, why do I have to specify inner classes, when i can just import all stuff dealing with hardware?

Comment: Just a note: One would only say "inner classes" if the classes are inside another class. Here, `android.hardware` is not a class, but a package. So these classes are still top-level classes. But yes, as has already been stated in answers, you can import every class in the `android.hardware` package that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can replace separate imports of classes that belong to one package by single import of "all" classes in the package by using

```
import android.hardware.*;
```

To prevent other questions I want to note that it does not affect neither performance nor memory consumption.

I however do not like and do not recommend this style because it sometimes causes some surprises when you import "wrong" class from other package. Usually IDE manages `import` statement very well, so you do not have to care about them at all, so I IMHO prefer using implicit import statements for each class.

Concerning to inner classes. In your example you do not have even one inner class, but if you have you have to specify the fully qualified class name exactly as in case of top level classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like java you can do that.Here hardware is your base package, it can replace all the sub class by this statement:

import android.hardware.*;

Comment: No, android.hardware is *not* a base-class. It is a package, which is something entirely different.